# Wordpress Include 'print_f' in WP_Customize_Control array

Tags: theme-customizer, array, translation, labels

I have the following problem: I want to add print_f in an array in wordpress.

```
printf( __('Option to share on %s', 'themename'), 'name')
```

However, the following code does not work properly for me. Instead of the actual result, it throws out "30"
.

```
$wp_customize->add_control(
                        new WP_Customize_Control(
                                $wp_customize,
                                'display-name'
                                array(
                                        'label' => printf( __('Option to share on %s', 'theme-name'), 'name'),
                                        'section' => 'share',
                                        'settings' => 'display-name',
                                        'type' => 'checkbox',
                                        'description' => 'Just a Description.'
                                        'active_callback' => 'share_callback',
                                )
                        )
                );
```

Hope someone can help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As documented](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php) (always read the docs), `printf()` returns:

> ...the length of the outputted string.

That's why you're getting 30.

If you're adding a value to an array or a string you need to use a function that *returns* a value. Not one that prints. `printf()` prints the value and returns the length of the printed value. To *return* a formatted string, you need to use `sprintf()`:

```
'label' => sprintf( __('Option to share on %s', 'theme-name'), 'name'),
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9387765/what-is-the-difference-between-php-echo-and-php-return-in-plain-english) for more on the difference between returning and printing/echoing.

Comment: Thank you, the option works great!